# Error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to deserialize an API json response into a list.
BUt I get teh error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Here is the code which I'm using to deserialize:

```
 var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EndofDay.Insrtumentxxx>>(Content);
```

Here is my class that contains the list:

```
public class EndofDay
{

    public Instrumentxxx instrumentxxx { get; set; }

    public class Instrumentxxx
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public double APrice { get; set; }
        public double BPrice { get; set; }
        public double CPrice { get; set; }


    }
}
```

}

Here is my json api response:

```
{\"instrumentxxx\":
[{\"id\":\"B1QH8P2\",
\"APrice\":5.83,
\"BPrice\":6.83,
\"CPrice\":7.83,}]}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The code that actually deserializes the string is missing.

Comment: Nothing in your example shows a `List` and the composite object of `id`, `APrice`, `BPrice`, `CPrice` is expectin an array/list.

Comment: Have added the deserialize code now.  @Ray sorry I'm not a wiz at c#, how do I change to array?

Comment: Does  `var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EndofDay.Insrtumentxxx>(Content);` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON response is array and you have declared as single object. You must declare `instrumentxxx as List<Instrumentxxx>`

Here is the working code [Click here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K6PNoo)

```
public class EndofDay
{

    public List<Instrumentxxx> instrumentxxx { get; set; }   
    
}

public class Instrumentxxx
{
   public string id { get; set; }
   public double APrice { get; set; }
   public double BPrice { get; set; }
   public double CPrice { get; set; }   
}
```

Comment: Updated the code, can you keep the `Instrumentxxx` class out side of `EndofDay` and try? And to which object you are deserializing? Is it `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EndofDay>(jsonString)`?

Comment: Yes correct, (Content) is where I'm saving the API response which is json format.

Comment: Moved Instrumentxxx outside of EndofDay class, still same error.

Comment: Added the working code, please refer that once. https://dotnetfiddle.net/K6PNoo